# Count distinct per fiscal year and display all dates in query result

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, window-functions

[**DB-Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1801c3166d877fb553e3561c292b5128):

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    order_date DATE,
    customerID VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, customerID
)
VALUES 
("2020-01-15", "Customer_01"),
("2020-02-15", "Customer_01"),
("2020-03-18", "Customer_01"),
("2020-04-22", "Customer_01"),
("2021-01-19", "Customer_01"),

("2020-01-25", "Customer_02"),
("2020-02-26", "Customer_02"),
("2020-11-23", "Customer_02"),
("2021-01-17", "Customer_02"),
("2021-02-20", "Customer_02");
```

**Expected Result:**

```
order_date   |      quantity
             |    (fiscal year)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-15   |           1         --> Customer_01 appears the first time between 2019-03 and 2020-02)
2020-01-25   |           1         --> Customer_02 appears the first time between 2019-03 and 2020-02)
2020-02-15   |           0
2020-02-26   |           0
2020-03-18   |           1         --> Customer_01 appears the first time between 2020-03 and 2021-02
2020-04-22   |           0
2020-11-23   |           1         --> Customer_02 appears the first time between 2020-03 and 2021-02
2021-01-17   |           0
2021-01-19   |           0
2021-02-20   |           0
```

---

In the above result I want to list all `order dates` and **count** the number of `customers` **distinct** per **fiscal year**. 
The `fiscal year` starts **two months** after the calender year and therefore goes from `March` to `February`. 
(e.g. from `2020-03` til `2021-02`).

For example `Customer_01` appears the first time on `2020-03-18` within the fiscal year `2020-03` til `2021-02`. 
Therefore, this `order_date` gets assigned `1` to it. 
If the customer appears again within the fiscal year the next `order_date` will get assigned `0` to it.

---

So far I have used this query:

```
SELECT
order_date,
SUM(rn = 1) AS quantity
FROM 
  (SELECT 
  order_date, 
  row_number() over(PARTITION BY YEAR(order_date), customerID ORDER BY order_date) rn
  FROM customers
  ) t
GROUP BY 1;
```

It works perfectly for the calender year. 
However, I have no clue how I can apply the two months shift from the fiscal year to it. 
Do you have any idea?

Comment: `PARTITION BY YEAR(order_date - INTERVAL 2 MONTH)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your query as below:

```
SELECT
order_date,
SUM(rn = 1) AS quantity
FROM 

  (SELECT 
  order_date, 
  row_number() over(PARTITION BY YEAR(order_date - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), customerID ORDER BY order_date) rn
  FROM customers
  ) t
  
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=7a6622af16395a803412a0f42f267a7d