# Count distinct number of customers per fiscal year and display all dates in query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3751415905633564dc4e1a9a020e110b)**

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    order_date DATE,
    customerID VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO customers
(order_date, customerID
)
VALUES 
('2020-01-15', 'Customer_01'),
('2020-02-03', 'Customer_01'),
('2020-02-15', 'Customer_01'),
('2020-03-18', 'Customer_01'),
('2020-03-20', 'Customer_01'),
('2020-04-22', 'Customer_01'),
('2021-01-19', 'Customer_01'),

('2020-01-25', 'Customer_02'),
('2020-02-26', 'Customer_02'),
('2020-11-23', 'Customer_02'),
('2021-01-17', 'Customer_02'),
('2021-02-20', 'Customer_02');
```

**Expected Result:**

```
order_date   |      quantity
             |    (fiscal year)
-------------|----------------------------------------------------
2020-01-15   |           1   --> Customer_01 appears the first time between 2019-03 and 2020-02
2020-01-25   |           1   --> Customer_02 appears the first time between 2019-03 and 2020-02
2020-02-03   |           0   
2020-02-15   |           0
2020-02-26   |           0
2020-03-18   |           1   --> Customer_01 appears the first time between 2020-03 and 2021-02
2020-03-20   |           0
2020-04-22   |           0
2020-11-23   |           1   --> Customer_02 appears the first time between 2020-03 and 2021-02
2021-01-17   |           0
2021-01-19   |           0
2021-02-20   |           0
```

---

In the above result I want to list all `order dates` and **count** the number of `customers` **distinct** per **fiscal year**. 
The `fiscal year` starts **two months** after the calender year and therefore goes from `March` to `February`. 
(e.g. from `2020-03` til `2021-02`).

For example `Customer_01` appears the first time on `2020-03-18` within the fiscal year `2020-03` til `2021-02`. 
Therefore, this `order_date` gets assigned `1` to it. 
If the customer appears again within the fiscal year the next `order_date` will get assigned `0` to it.

---

With reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521484/count-distinct-per-fiscal-year-and-display-all-dates-in-query-result) in `MariaDB` I was able to achieve the expected result as you can see in the [DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=b29146f198d7f279ac8e89ad7a3a83ec).

However, now I want to get the same results using `postgresSQL`. 
Therefore, I have modified the query so far to this:

```
SELECT
order_date,
SUM(rn = 1) AS quantity
FROM 

  (SELECT 
  order_date, 
  row_number() over(PARTITION BY DATE_PART('year', (order_date - INTERVAL '2 month')::date), customerID ORDER BY order_date) rn
  FROM customers
  ) t
  
GROUP BY 1;
```

However, now I am getting an error `function sum(boolean) does not exist` on the `SUM(rn = 1)` part. 
What is the equivalnt syntax for the `SUM(rn = 1)` in `postgresSQL` to achieve the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation I came up with the following solution:

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=48924bcff473ec486cf5537a0505317f)**

```
SELECT
order_date,
(CASE WHEN t.rolling_count > 1 THEN 0 ELSE t.rolling_count END) AS quantity
FROM 

  (SELECT 
  order_date, 
  (row_number() over(PARTITION BY DATE_PART('year', (order_date - INTERVAL '2 month')::date), customerID ORDER BY order_date)) AS rolling_count
  FROM customers
  ORDER BY 1
  ) t
  
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1;
```

---

As comparison here is the **[MariaDB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=af6a95cd64170774cdee6e2d12bf9431)** of the query:

```
SELECT
order_date,
(CASE WHEN t.rolling_count > 1 THEN 0 ELSE t.rolling_count END) AS quantity
FROM 

  (SELECT 
  order_date, 
  (row_number() over(PARTITION BY YEAR(order_date - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), customerID ORDER BY order_date)) AS rolling_count
  FROM customers
  ORDER BY 1
  ) t
  
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to this problem.  One is determining the fiscal year.  The second is doing the distinct count.

The first is solved by subtracting two months and extracting the date.  The second is logically:

```
select c.*,
       count(distinct customerId) over (partition by fyyyy order by order_date)
from (select c.*, date_trunc('year', order_date - interval '2 month') as fyyyy
      from customers c
     ) c
order by date;
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in Postgres.  But you can instead just count the first time that a customer appears:

```
select c.*,
       count(*) filter (where seqnum = 1) over (partition by fyyyy order by order_date)
from (select c.*,
             date_trunc('year', order_date - interval '2 month') as fyyyy,
             row_number() over (partition by customerId, date_trunc('year', order_date - interval '2 month')
                                order by order_date
                               ) as seqnum
      from customers c
     ) c
order by order_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b8ab948adac890d9691ddf3ffe9b233d) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: So there is no way to ever get the expected result wiht postgresSQL?

Comment: Would it be possible in redshift or will there be the same issue?

Comment: The question is tagged Postgres, not Redshfit.  You already know they are different.  In any case, you just need to replace the `filter` with `sum( (seqnum = 1)::int )` for Redshfit.